# Chart.js - add gradient instead of solid color

Tags: chart.js

I'm using chart.js but I cannot figure out how to make a background color with a gradient looking like that: http://jsfiddle.net/4vobe59a/

I read a few questions here on Stack Overflow but with my knowledge I'm still not able to implement them to my case. What can I try next?

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react'

import { ChartOptions } from 'chart.js'

import { LineChart as BaseLineChart } from '../base/LineChart'
import { colorScheme } from './colors'

const formatter = (
  ranges: any[],
  data: any,
  labelKey: string,
  dataKey: string
) => {
  const result = []

  for (const range of ranges) {
    const item = data.find((item: any) => item[labelKey] === range)

    if (item) {
      result.push(item[dataKey])
    } else {
      result.push(null)
    }
  }

  return result
}

const getDefaultLabels = (data: any, labelKey: string) => {
  const labels: { [key: string]: string } = {}
  for (const key of Object.keys(data)) {
    for (const item of data[key]) {
      labels[item[labelKey]] = item[labelKey]
    }
  }

  return Object.values(labels)
}

const buildData = ({
  data,
  dataKey,
  labelFormatter,
  labelKey,
  getLabels,
}: {
  data: any
  dataKey: string
  labelFormatter?: (value: string) => string
  labelKey: string
  getLabels?: (value: any, labelKey: string) => string[] | number[]
}) => {
  const labels =
    getLabels && typeof getLabels === 'function'
      ? getLabels(data, labelKey)
      : getDefaultLabels(data, labelKey)

  return {
    labels,
    datasets: Object.keys(data).map((key: string, index) => ({
      label: labelFormatter ? labelFormatter(key) : key,
      data: formatter(labels, data[key], labelKey, dataKey),
      backgroundColor: colorScheme[index],
      borderColor: colorScheme[index],

    })),
  }
}

function LineChart({
  options = {},
  data,
  dataKey,
  labelKey,
  labelFormatter,
  getLabels,
}: {
  options?: Partial<ChartOptions<'line'>>
  data: any
  dataKey: string
  labelKey: string
  labelFormatter?: (value: string) => string
  getLabels?: (value: any, labelKey: string) => string[] | number[]
}) {
  const chartData = useMemo(
    () => buildData({ data, dataKey, labelKey, labelFormatter, getLabels }),
    [data, dataKey, labelFormatter, labelKey, getLabels]
  )

  return <BaseLineChart options={options} data={chartData} />
}

export default LineChart
```

Comment: Maybe you can have a look to chartjs-plugin-gradient: https://github.com/kurkle/chartjs-plugin-gradient

Comment: There is also a specific sample about gradient in CHART.JS doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/advanced/linear-gradient.html